# Blackberry Push Notifications Client Sample

Tags: blackberry, push-notification

I am trying to install the sample application with push notifications enabled.

I download the sample code from here : [BB sample app](https://developer.blackberry.com/java/documentation/download_build_sample_app.html)

On the device when i hit register i get the error :

```
Some of the setting are empty or NULL. Please make sure that all of
the following are set in the application settings: application ID , 
content provider URL, and BPS URL
```

What exactly shall i do i dont understand the error.

Also what shall i do to enable BIS ? I am not a BB user , i just need to develop an app for it , but i have no previous experience using it. The phone came with a SIM card that has 3g internet. That means that the BIS is enabled?

I am developing for OS < 7.x

Comment: if you want to test push notifications, you have to activate BIS on your devise(for that contact the network provider).

Comment: i ve heard that a lot of times. What exactly is BIS ? The phone works with wifi and with the sim card with 3g. I mean i have internet both ways. That doesnt mean is activated?

Comment: BIS means blackberry internet service. Its an internet service provided only for blackberry users. You have to ask for the network provider for the activation of bis.